# Delete blank columns

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

This must be a common problem, but I couldn't find a solution.
I have several files which have different sets of columns which are completely blank (for all rows except header) , how can I delete these columns from the files?

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
 1       2                3              43
         1                3               3
```

So I don't want col3 and col5 in the output since they are blank.

Please help.

This is the desired output. Files are tab delimited.

```
col1    col2    col4    col6
1        2      3        43
         1      3         3
```

Comment: What kind of files are you processing? Your example could refer to some sort of binary (e.g. Excel) or tab-separated file.

Comment: Could you show us your desired output? Should the header be kept? Should the columns be renamed?

Comment: What is the field separator?

Comment: Files are tab delimited, the header of only the non-blank columns are to be retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl solution, suitable for smaller files that can fit into memory. For larger files, you'd need to process the file twice. I assumed the input files are tab separated.

The `%empty` hash keeps the list of indices of the empty columns. If a column is populated, it's removed from the hash. So, once the whole file is saved into the @array, the %empty contains exactly the columns that were never populated.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

chomp(my @header = split "\t", <>);
my %empty;
@empty{ 0 .. $#header } = (1) x @header;  # Start with ones for each column.

my @array;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @array, [ split "\t" ];
    undef $empty{$_} for grep length $array[-1][$_], 0 .. $#header;
}

for my $line (\@header, @array) {
    say join "\t",
        map $line->[$_] // q(),  # Turn uninitialized values to empty strings.
        grep ! $empty{$_},
        0 .. $#header;
}
```

Comment: tab-separation assumption is pretty crucial here :) Also, you might want to print out the header. "say"? I'm not familiar with that feature.

Comment: @Otheus: With just spaces, you'd have to deduce the column widths from the header. Doable, but boring :)

Comment: Might want to output the header somehow before the for loop

Comment: @Otheus: Easily fixed by prepending `\@header` to the for loop list.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this code (I consider myself an increasingly-obsolete perl-buff), but this `@empty{ 0 .. $#header } = (1) x @header` line I don't get. In the perl debugger, `x \@empty` shows an empty array. Did you perhaps mean `@empty[ 0 .. $#header ] ...` ?

Comment: @Otheus: Try `\%empty` instead.

Comment: Cool. So what does `@empty{ ... }` do? Creates a hash from the list inside the brackets?

Comment: @Otheus: It's `@hash{@keys} = @values`.

Comment: @Otheus `(1) x @header` is an array of ones as long as `@header`. For example, `perl -le '@a=(1,2,3); print "foo" x @a'` will print `foofoofoo`.

Comment: I grok'd the RHS; it was the LHS I didn't understand till choroba' commented and I tested in perl debug. I'm astounded I never new that. Actually, using @H to the argument of `x` was new to me, but I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask for [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), but this is pretty fun:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  columns = CSV.read(ARGV.shift, :col_sep => "\t").transpose 
  trimmed = columns.select {|col| col if col[1..-1].find {|elem| not elem.nil?}}
  trimmed.transpose.each {|row| puts row.join("\t")}
' file
```

produces

```
col1    col2    col4    col6
1       2       3       43
        1       3       3
```